# Hard Code a row in jqgrid

Tags: jqgrid

I have a jqgrid in which name .SSN , role and email addresses are stored. Now at the end of this jqgrid I want a hardcoded value in grid in which name would be notification email and email would be abc@hotmail.com

```
            colNames:['name','Role','SSN','EmailAddress'],
colModel:[
    {name: 'name',index: 'name',sortable:false,search:false,sorttype: 'text'},
           {name: 'role',index: 'role',sortable:false,search:false,sorttype: 'text'},
           {name: 'ssN',index: 'ssN',sortable:false,search:false,sorttype: 'text'},
           {name: 'emailAddress',index: 'emailAddress',sortable:false,search:false,sorttype: 'text'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [custom formatter](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acustom_formatter)

```
{name: 'emailAddress',index: 'emailAddress',sortable:false,search:false,sorttype: 'text',formatter:testFormatter}
```

and the function

```
                function testFormatter ( cellvalue, options, rowObject )
                {

                return "email@mymailcompany.com";
                }
```